# Painting red over white oil-based primer

Tags: painting, primer, oil-based-paint

I stripped paint off this nonferrous metal mailbox, then applied oil based primer:

[image]

I would like to paint the mailbox the same paint (color/sheen/grade) as the rest of the house, visible above it. I know that red-ish paints require gray primer and this is white. Will this red-ish paint be appropriate for this primer or should I pick a color that will?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference is that a red paint will "seem to cover" a gray primer somewhat more easily than a white primer.  That is, it will take fewer coats to make it look good.

All paints allow a certain degree of "print-through".  That is, if you painted a checkerboard with 1 coat, you could still see the checkerboard pattern. That is just a practicality of how paints are made. The answer is more coats - with enough coats, even the checkerboard would be hidden.

In a perfect world, you make the primer *exactly* the color of the topcoat.  **It will print through** just as badly as the checkerboard. But you won't notice! LOL!

So that's what the gray is all about.  Color has 3 traits:

- Hue
- Lightness
- Chroma (saturation)

Lightness tends to be what prints through strongest, so the goal with gray primer is to get the *lightness* closer.  So that print-through will be less obvious.

For instance, I have both white and gray primer in one paint system.  When painting yellow, I mix the primers about 6:1 (a little gray goes a long way) giving a light gray, probably a Munsell 9/ in lightness. (0-10). It works better with the yellow than white does.

Red is particularly difficult, *since good pigments are Just Not Available anymore*.  You probably don't want cinnabar, since it's mercury. So reds tend to be worse than average with print-through.

So, what does "more difficult" mean?  It simply means **more coats to get good coverage**.

Overcoating will work, provided you follow the manufacturers' instructions regarding compatibility and cure times.

Comment: so bottom line, do you think i should choose another color (e.g. blue) that fits on a white primer or it would be good to proceed with red?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I left off the conclusion @amphibent. As long as you're willing to add a 3rd or 4th coat as needed, you can paint any color you want over white.

Answer (score -1):

It should work okay as long as the primer is fully cured.

Comment: what does "fully cured" mean/imply?

Comment: What does "should work OK" mean? Will red look sufficiently red over a white primer, or will the color appear to be different than the red on OP's house because it was (presumably) over a grey primer?

Comment: The word "cured" means that the chemical reaction that hardens a resin or paint has finished taking place. It is similar to the word "dried", but that strictly refers to water based paints.

Comment: It "should work OK" means that it should work well enough.